# How do i change 0's to 1's and 1's to 0's in a string using python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

For example my input is "100101", the output should be "011010" 
here is my code 
but its giving error.
thank you.

```
s=raw_input()
for i in range(len(s)):
if(s[i]=='1'):
    s[i]='0'
if(s[i]=='0'):
    s[i]='1'
```

print s

Comment: **what** error are you getting? Do you understand **what** this error **means**?

Comment: Your error maybe is because strings are immutable. You can rather translate the characters. You cannot do item assignments with strings

Answer (score 1):

Your error maybe is because strings are immutable. You cannot do item assignments with strings. On the other hand You can make a translation table where 0 is mapped to 1 and 1 is mapped to 0 then translate the string `a`

```
 a  = "100101"    
 a.translate(a.maketrans("01","10"))

 '011010'
```

Comment: It may be worth to explain *why* OP is getting an error instead of just providing them with a working piece of code